# get occurrence of string in generic list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics

I have a list like listed below, I need count of occurrence of time to be updated in occurrence count, Its not just getting total occurrence of string in list, Suppose Group1 is appearing second time occurrence count of that item should be updated as 2, If it appears one more time that particular occurrence should be updated as 3. This can be done using a loop and increment the count according to occurrence of group, Is there any better way to do this using linq or some other technique.

For example, with the following list:

```
public class Category
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int OccuranceCount { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var categories = new List<Category>
    {
        new Category {Id = 1, Name = "Group"},
        new Category {Id = 1, Name = "Group2"},
        new Category {Id = 1, Name = "Group1"},
        new Category {Id = 1, Name = "Group2"},
        new Category {Id = 1, Name = "Group"},
        new Category {Id = 1, Name = "Group3"},
        new Category {Id = 1, Name = "Group"}
    };

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I need to output something like this:

```
Name      Occurrence Count
Group     0
Group2    0
Group1    0
Group2    1
Group     1
Group3    0
Group     2
```

My currrent code

```
        foreach (var category in categories)
        {
            var selectedCategory = categories.Where(x => x.Name.Equals(category.Name));

            category.OccuranceCount =
                categories.Where(x => x.Name.Equals(category.Name)).Max(x => x.OccuranceCount) + 1;
        }
        foreach (var category in categories)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name : {0}, OccuranceCount {1}",category.Name, category.OccuranceCount);
        }
```

Comment: Do I understand this correctly: If you insert a `Category` into the list with the same `Name` string that another `Category` instance in that list already has, you want to increment that Category's OccuranceCount? Do you wish to keep both Categories in the list or not?

Comment: "Is there any better way" Can you *show* your current approach? It´s hard to get your idea.

Comment: @HimBromBeere added code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LINQ `GroupBy` combined with fancy `Select` overload with index, but since you need to update the entries anyway, IMO the best from time and space complexity would be to use a simple counting dictionary:

```
var counts = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach (var category in categories)
{
    int count;
    counts.TryGetValue(category.Name, out count);
    counts[category.Name] = category.OccuranceCount = ++count;
}
```

For the record, here is the LINQ version:

```
foreach (var group in categories.GroupBy(c => c.Name))
    foreach (var item in group.Select((category, index) => new { category, index }))
        item.category.OccuranceCount = item.index + 1;
```